# Good looking contributed themes for Drupal 6

Tags: 6, theming

I am looking for good looking contributed themes fro Drupal 6. Drupal.org is filled with themes, although several of them lack support even for the most used modules (taxonomy, search, comment) and many are table based or written through bad and horrible practices.

What I would like to see are modern themes with great typography, grids, good coding practices, based on starter themes, making good use of CSS3 features, supporting other modules. I know it's hard to see a theme with all of those qualities, but try to match at least *two* of these.

Comment: "Good looking theme" is rather subjective.

Comment: Yes, but 'well written', and a lack of 'horrible practices' are not subjective...perhaps it needs a new title.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a list of good resources, upvoted by the community. Of course, there's no final answer to this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for recommendations or suggestions on hosting, tools, modules, themes, distributions, books, tutorials, documentation, or other off-site resources.

Answer (score 1):

While not definitive, looking at [the list sorted by number of installs](http://drupal.org/project/themes?filters=drupal_core:87%20bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) is probably a good place to start regarding coding standards, and wide support.

Further filtering this list using some of your keywords like 'starter', 'css3', 'html5', etc should help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: can you post this as a comment? this isn't actually an answer. I want to make one of those "Good suggestions" questions of StackOverflow, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023451/drupal-best-forum-module

Comment: There is no definitive answer to your question. If you're looking for 'theme foo' is the best, then I agree with kiamlaluno that this question is too subjective.

Comment: see comment on the question.